# How to make the R.java has different values in 2 android application?

Tags: android

I'm writing a plugin-enabled android application here.
I have 2 applications(2 apk), one is main program and another is a plugin.

Now I want the plugin constructs it's own interface in main program's Activity. But I found the R.java in 2 applications has the same values:

The R.java in plugin:

```
public final class R {
    public static final class attr {
    }
    public static final class drawable {
        public static final int icon=0x7f020000;
    }
    public static final class id {
        public static final int button1=0x7f050000;
        public static final int button2=0x7f050001;
    }
    public static final class layout {
        public static final int widget=0x7f030000;
    }
    public static final class string {
        public static final int app_name=0x7f040000;
        public static final int button1text=0x7f040001;
        public static final int button2text=0x7f040002;
    }
}
```

And, R.java of main program:

```
public final class R {
    public static final class attr {
    }
    public static final class drawable {
        public static final int icon=0x7f020000;
    }
    public static final class id {
        public static final int mainWidgetLayout=0x7f050000;
    }
    public static final class layout {
        public static final int main=0x7f030000;
    }
    public static final class string {
        public static final int app_name=0x7f040001;
        public static final int hello=0x7f040000;
    }
}
```

Just as you can see, there are a lot of same values in these 2 R.java, this makes chaos. In plugin, if I wanna construct the interface via resource defined in R.java, it may refer to the same value in main program resource.

So, how to handle this? Is it possible to make the 2 R.java in 2 applications have different values?
Thanks a lot. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Having the values be different would just get you a resource not found exception anyway. Asking a Resources instance from the main app for a resource using an ID from a different app just doesn't make any sense, similar for layouts, etc.. Your best bet would be to try to get a Resources instance for the plugin from the PackageManager class. I don't know if that works off hand. It wouldn't matter if the IDs were the same as the IDs in the main app, though, anyway. You might want to rephrase your question. Having the ID values be different is useless.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I haven't done that myself, but the [following thread](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/566c9c6f79aa62c5?pli=1) might be of interest.
Especially the part saying

> Each resource identifier consists of 32 bits were 8 top bits defines
>   the
>   package in which the resource belongs to. Platform resources are 0x01
>   and 0x7F are application resources. The idea is to use the remaining
>   253 values for extension packages.

So you might be able to generate different resource identifiers using aapt -x (launch aapt without arguments to get a list of options).

Comment: Thank you, Julien. "aapt -x" works, I use this command and get a new R.java. Thanks. ~/Android/programs/android-sdk-linux_86/platforms/android-8/tools/aapt package -f -m -x -J ~/Android/workspace/AcsPluginGuiMainWidget/gen -S res -I ~/Android/programs/android-sdk-linux_86/platforms/android-8/android.jar -M AndroidManifest.xml